# sql SELECT WHERE-insufficient bindings

Tags: sql, select, binding, where-clause

I am using only two columns 1.name 2.field. i need to retrieve name where field is =? how to specify.i dont want this--> (self.topic_space,)) i need the second column.so where to put the comma

Here is my code :

```
   cur.execute("SELECT name FROM developers_info WHERE field=?",(,self.topic_space))
     File "administrator.py", line 19
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM developers_info WHERE field=?",(,self.topic_space))
                                                           ^
```

Here is my error :

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may have a rogue comma. Try this

```
 cur.execute("SELECT name FROM developers_info WHERE field=?",(self.topic_space))
```

Comment: i tried it before.this was the result : Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.

Comment: ok now everythings fine got the answer by myself.thankyou for helping